# store image into XML/CSV or Disk?

Tags: css, xml, database, csv

we store`image` files into database as *BLOB* type, but i have to save the image files into `XML/CSV`. as far as i understand XML is text based and it can only save data as text format so the images need to change to base64. Right?

OR i am thinking to save image somewhere in disk and give the `url` into XML. BTW i haven't much idea about data base, please give me any idea to save image files into `csv/xml`.

***Requirement for this appl'n :*** There is a customized web application which provides to edit css including modify `background image url` and in process of edit the web-page's `image/button`, it uploads image from client, saves into (`??? this is my question, Where ?`) and linked with web-page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you save the image file onto the disk, then put the filepath into the database, rather than the actually binary data.

This way you get the benefit of easy HTTP serving, as well as a smaller database and easier incremental backups of both.

Comment: Thanks Rich for clearing my doubt.BTW where should i save these image files 'in context or outside of context.'

Comment: I'd save them somewhere like /assets/custom_images/ inside your document root so you can access them directly by visiting http://example.com/assets/custom_images/image99.jpg . It's worth renaming them, maybe based on database ID, or by userID to make them trivial to access without multiple DB queries.

Comment: Yes Rich, i am almost right but using `assets/custom_image/session id/_image.jpg_`. where `session id` is a individual directory for each client. is it worth to use `session id`?

Comment: Depends on how many images/users you have. If you aren't Facebook/eBay sized, then it's personal preference.

Comment: ok. but what could be better according to you if it's open to all (`no authenticity for user`) and yes it's not like _facebook/eBay_ but an user can upload & save many images.

Comment: I'd put images in a folder named after the users id.